# Single SSL for multiple IP address

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, ssl

I have two servers one for client and one for API calls. I have installed an SSL to the client server. Now my client side is blocking all calls being made to my API server which doesn't have SSL cert.

My questions are:

Will I be able to use the same SSL cert. on my API server being they both have two different IP addresses?

Will adding a subdomain that points to my API server work?

I am using:

NodeJS/express for both client and API servers

AWS Route53, LoadBalancer, EC2 for client side

AWS EC2 for server side

Im not entirely sure how to go about this.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you use subdomains? If so, just use a wildcard certificate and that'll work for all subdomains.

Comment: Got it. I'll try adding a subdomain that points to the API server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL is domain based, not ip based.

If your SSL Certificate of Type is Wildcard (*.example.com) you can for both client and API servers ,

or

If Type is Single Certificate (cleint.example.com and server.example.com) again there is no problem because they have the same domain names.

Comment: "SSL is domain based, not ip based.". SSL or more precisely TLS is not based anything. It is a protocol to exchange data with some guarantees (integrity, confidentiality, authentication). The authentication part CAN (and often is) use X.509 certificates, and those certificates OFTEN pertain to a domain name. But you can have X.509 certificates on IP addresses. Not recommended for HTTPS operations, but useful in other cases. It is important to clearly separate TLS from X.509.